# Spring service layer object comes null

Tags: spring, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

Hi I am learning Spring and has stuck to a problem.
I have a structure something like the following:

```
package com.edfx.model;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

private long customer_id;
private String name;
private String address;
private Date created_date;


@Id
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
public long getCustomer_id() {
    return customer_id;
}

public void setCustomer_id(long customer_id) {
    this.customer_id = customer_id;
}


@Column(name = "NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@Column(name = "ADDRESS")
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}


@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
public Date getCreated_date() {
    return created_date;
}

public void setCreated_date(Date created_date) {
    this.created_date = created_date;
}

@Override
public String toString(){

    StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    strBuffer.append("customer_id:").append(getCustomer_id());
    strBuffer.append(", name : ").append(getName());
    strBuffer.append(", address: ").append(getAddress());
    strBuffer.append(", created_date: ").append(getCreated_date());
    return strBuffer.toString();
}

}
```

The Managed Bean is:

```
package com.edfx.managedbean;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import com.edfx.customer.service.ICustomerService;
import com.edfx.model.Customer;

@ManagedBean(name = "customerMB")
@SessionScoped
public class CustomerManagedBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8839370045113377019L;

private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String ERROR = "error";

// Spring Customer Service Injection
ICustomerService customerService;

public ICustomerService getCustomerService() {
    System.out.println("customerService -- >"+customerService);
    return customerService;
}

public void setCustomerService(ICustomerService customerService) {
    this.customerService = customerService;
}

List<Customer> userList;
private long customer_id;
private String name;
private String address;
private Date created_date;

public String addUser(){

    System.out.println("Managed Bean Add User..");
    try {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        System.out.println("ID :: "+getCustomer_id());
        customer.setCustomer_id(getCustomer_id());
        System.out.println("Name :: "+getName());
        customer.setName(getName());
        System.out.println("Address :: "+getAddress());
        customer.setAddress(getAddress());
        System.out.println("Created Date :: "+new Date());
        customer.setCreated_date(new Date());

        //Service Provider
        getCustomerService().addUser(customer);
        return SUCCESS;

    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        System.err.println("Error Occured :: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return ERROR;
}

public void reset(){
    this.setCustomer_id(0);
    this.setName("");
    this.setAddress("");
    this.setCreated_date(null);
}

public List<Customer> getUserList(){

    userList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    System.out.println("BEAN :: "+getCustomerService().getUsers());
    userList.addAll(getCustomerService().getUsers());
    return userList;
}


public void setUserList(List<Customer> userList) {
    this.userList = userList;
}

public long getCustomer_id() {
    return customer_id;
}

public void setCustomer_id(long customer_id) {
    this.customer_id = customer_id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public Date getCreated_date() {
    return created_date;
}

public void setCreated_date(Date created_date) {
    this.created_date = created_date;
}

}
```

The applicationContextFile is:

```
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.edfx.managedbean"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Bean Declaration -->
    <bean id="Customer" class="com.edfx.model.Customer"/>

    <!-- Customer Service Declaration -->
    <bean id="customerService" class="com.edfx.customer.service.CustomerService" scope="prototype">
        <property name="customerDAO" ref="CustomerDAO"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Customer DAO Declaration -->
    <bean id="CustomerDAO" class="com.edfx.customer.dao.CustomerDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
    <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase"/>
        <property name="user" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.edfx.model.Customer</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behaviour based on annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="runMeJob"/>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronTrigger"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Spring Configuration Manager -->
    <bean id="runMeTask" class="com.edfx.customer.schedular.RunMeTask"/>

    <!-- Spring Quartz -->
    <bean name="runMeJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.edfx.customer.schedular.RunMeJob"/>

        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="runMeTask" value-ref="runMeTask"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Simple Trigger every 5 secs
    <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob"/>
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000"/>
        <property name="stratDelay" value="1000"/>
    </bean> -->


    <!-- CronTrigger runs every 5 secs-->
    <bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob"/>
        <property name="misfireInstructionName" value="MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 30 19 * * ?"/>
    </bean>
```

Here I have set a schedular. The scheduler works absolutely fine as it fires properly at the specific time.

Here is the Job details that is scheduled to run:

```
package com.edfx.customer.schedular;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader;
import com.edfx.customer.ldap.mngr.LDAPManager;
import com.edfx.customer.service.CustomerService;
import com.edfx.customer.service.ICustomerLdapSyncService;
import com.edfx.customer.service.ICustomerService;
import com.edfx.managedbean.CustomerManagedBean;
import com.edfx.model.Customer;
public class RunMeJob extends QuartzJobBean{

 private RunMeTask runMeTask;

@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;
    try {
        applicationContext = (ApplicationContext)context.getScheduler().getContext().get("applicationContext");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Synchronization Error :: "+e.getMessage());
    }

    if(applicationContext == null)
        applicationContext = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
    System.out.println("=============== SCHEDULAR SERVICE ON =================");
    System.out.println("MAP DETAILS == >"+new LDAPManager().getUserDetails());
    Map<String, String> userDetailsMap = new LDAPManager().getUserDetails();

    CustomerManagedBean customerManagedBean = new CustomerManagedBean();
    int i=0;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : userDetailsMap.entrySet()){
        i++;
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("Key -->"+key+" :: Value-->"+value);
        customerManagedBean.setCustomer_id(i);
        customerManagedBean.setName(key);
        customerManagedBean.setAddress(value);
        customerManagedBean.setCreated_date(new Date());
    }
    customerManagedBean.addUser();
    runMeTask.printMe();
    System.out.println("=============== SCHEDULAR SERVICE OFF ================");
}

public void setRunMeTask(RunMeTask runMeTask) {
    this.runMeTask = runMeTask;
}
}
```

Here, the method `addUser()` invokes properly. But while executing `getCustomerService().addUser(customer);` it throws `NullPointerException` as it gets `customerService` object null, which has been injected in the `CustomerManagedBean` class. mentioned in `applicationContext.xml`.

What could be the possible reason for this?
Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

First problem I found is that, in your `executeInternal` method you are not using `customerManagedBean` from your Spring application context. Instead of that, you are creating one like bellow:

```
CustomerManagedBean customerManagedBean = new CustomerManagedBean();
```

And when you are creating your own bean, its your responsibility to prepare it before use (injection or initialization), because you are not using it from any context made and managed by any framework (Spring or something else). You could avoid these problems by simply getting the bean from Spring's ApplicationContext, by replacing the above line with the line bellow:

```
CustomerManagedBean customerManagedBean = (CustomerManagedBean)applicationContext.getBean("beanName")
```

Second thing,

***Are you using JSF with Spring?***

If your answer is *no*, then why you are using JSF annotations (`@ManagedBean` and `@SessionScoped`). As these annotations are not recognizable to Spring. Spring actually doesn't instantiate it in its context. Although you putted,

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.edfx.managedbean"/>
```

in your  `applicationContext.xml`.

If your answer is *yes*, then you should follow, the following tutorials properly to configure successfully:

- [jsf 2.0 spring integration example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/)
- [jsf 2.0 spring hibernate integration example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/)

Comment: Thanks..It would definitely get back to you, after correcting my faults. Let me just check on the corrections that I have to make. And Yes, I am using JSF with Spring.

Comment: Okay! You can let me know your progress!